# What song plays in this scene of Doctor Who?

Tags: doctor-who

Can anyone help me identify this song?

Answer (score 5):

This is *[The Doctor's Theme: Series Four](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Doctor%27s_Theme)*, played by the BBC National Orchestra of Wales, an original composition by Murray Gold.